# Transform multiple files in a directory in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I have a folder with the name Translated_cds.
in this folder, there are 52 text files. these are FASTA files that have information about proteins.

```
>lcl|NZ_JPMI01000003.1_prot_WP_043388330.1_1 [locus_tag=Q664_RS00010] [protein=HAMP domain-containing protein] [protein_id=WP_043388330.1] [location=complement(30..1904)] [gbkey=CDS]
MRIRTRLLLLLIVTAAVPTLAVGLLAWRDAERALSEAVAEQHRRTALAEAEHAATHVLSLATELGGALVHQEPLELGPSE
AQEFLIRVFLRRDRIAQVGLFDARGQLTASVFVDDPEAFARQEPQFRRHDTVAAGEVEDFQRRASELLSQVPEGRAYAIS
APYLTGVRRRPAVVVAARAPGTRTGGLAAELGLEELSQRLAARGVGDERVFLLDGAGRLLLDGEPERERHEDFTGKLPGA
VGARQTGLAAYEEEGRAWLAAYSPVPELGWVAVVARPREAALAPLHALARSTYGVLGLTLLGVLALALMLARALARPIAR
LAEGARALARGNLAHRISLKRRDELGDLARAFNDMGQALEQAHRELLGFNEQLAAQVEERTRELQQTQVQLSRSQRLAAM
GDLAAGMAHEMNNPLAAVLGNVQLMLMDLPKEDPSHRMLGTVHQQAQRIASIVRELQLLSERQQLGRLPLDLHRMLQRVL
ESRCAELSQVGVHVDCRFHPGEVKVLGDTQALGDVLGRLLGNALNAMRDRPERNLVLSTQVVDAEVVRVEMKDTGRGIAR
EHLERIFNPFFTTKQQWTGKGLSLAVCHRVIEDHGGTITLDSVEGVGTTVTLVLPAAPASSGLV
```

the line starting with > (called the header)is present in all the files. I want to replace the gap ' ' in the headers with _.

till now i have tried this

```
sed -i 's/ /_/g' Translated_cds*
```

Comment: `till now i have tried this` did it work?

Comment: I cant see a code.

Comment: `I cant see a code.` there will be no output, the `-i` flag tells `sed` to edit files _in place_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can lead with `/^>/` to gate the substitution so that it isolates to the pattern we are interested in:

```
sed -i -e '/^>/ s/ /_/g' Translated_cds*
```

My test:

```
echo '>lcl|NZ_JPMI01000003.1_prot_WP_043388330.1_1 [locus_tag=Q664_RS00010] [protein=HAMP domain-containing protein] [protein_id=WP_043388330.1] [location=complement(30..1904)] [gbkey=CDS]
MRIRTRLLLLLIVTAAVPTLAVGLLAWRDAERALSEAVAEQHRRTALAEAEHAATHVLSLATELGGALVHQEPLELGPSE
AQEFLIRVFLRRDRIAQVGLFDARGQLTASVFVDDPEAFARQEPQFRRHDTVAAGEVEDFQRRASELLSQVPEGRAYAIS
APYLTGVRRRPAVVVAARAPGTRTGGLAAELGLEELSQRLAARGVGDERVFLLDGAGRLLLDGEPERERHEDFTGKLPGA
VGARQTGLAAYEEEGRAWLAAYSPVPELGWVAVVARPREAALAPLHALARSTYGVLGLTLLGVLALALMLARALARPIAR
LAEGARALARGNLAHRISLKRRDELGDLARAFNDMGQALEQAHRELLGFNEQLAAQVEERTRELQQTQVQLSRSQRLAAM
GDLAAGMAHEMNNPLAAVLGNVQLMLMDLPKEDPSHRMLGTVHQQAQRIASIVRELQLLSERQQLGRLPLDLHRMLQRVL
ESRCAELSQVGVHVDCRFHPGEVKVLGDTQALGDVLGRLLGNALNAMRDRPERNLVLSTQVVDAEVVRVEMKDTGRGIAR
EHLERIFNPFFTTKQQWTGKGLSLAVCHRVIEDHGGTITLDSVEGVGTTVTLVLPAAPASSGLV' | sed -e '/^>/ s/ /_/g'
```

My result:

```
>lcl|NZ_JPMI01000003.1_prot_WP_043388330.1_1_[locus_tag=Q664_RS00010]_[protein=HAMP_domain-containing_protein]_[protein_id=WP_043388330.1]_[location=complement(30..1904)]_[gbkey=CDS]
MRIRTRLLLLLIVTAAVPTLAVGLLAWRDAERALSEAVAEQHRRTALAEAEHAATHVLSLATELGGALVHQEPLELGPSE
AQEFLIRVFLRRDRIAQVGLFDARGQLTASVFVDDPEAFARQEPQFRRHDTVAAGEVEDFQRRASELLSQVPEGRAYAIS
APYLTGVRRRPAVVVAARAPGTRTGGLAAELGLEELSQRLAARGVGDERVFLLDGAGRLLLDGEPERERHEDFTGKLPGA
VGARQTGLAAYEEEGRAWLAAYSPVPELGWVAVVARPREAALAPLHALARSTYGVLGLTLLGVLALALMLARALARPIAR
LAEGARALARGNLAHRISLKRRDELGDLARAFNDMGQALEQAHRELLGFNEQLAAQVEERTRELQQTQVQLSRSQRLAAM
GDLAAGMAHEMNNPLAAVLGNVQLMLMDLPKEDPSHRMLGTVHQQAQRIASIVRELQLLSERQQLGRLPLDLHRMLQRVL
ESRCAELSQVGVHVDCRFHPGEVKVLGDTQALGDVLGRLLGNALNAMRDRPERNLVLSTQVVDAEVVRVEMKDTGRGIAR
EHLERIFNPFFTTKQQWTGKGLSLAVCHRVIEDHGGTITLDSVEGVGTTVTLVLPAAPASSGLV
```

If we want only the spaces within the keyword/value tags of the header replaced, then:

```
sed -i -e '/^>/ s/\([A-Za-z0-9]\) \([[A-Za-z0-9]\)/\1_\2/g' Translated_cds*
```

Or.... We can clarify a bit with more modern regex:

```
sed -i -E '/^>/ s/([[:alnum:]]) ([[:alnum:]])/\1_\2/g' Translated_cds*
```

The result will change only inside the header's keyword/value tags:

```
>lcl|NZ_JPMI01000003.1_prot_WP_043388330.1_1 [locus_tag=Q664_RS00010] [protein=HAMP_domain-containing_protein] [protein_id=WP_043388330.1] [location=complement(30..1904)] [gbkey=CDS]
MRIRTRLLLLLIVTAAVPTLAVGLLAWRDAERALSEAVAEQHRRTALAEAEHAATHVLSLATELGGALVHQEPLELGPSE
AQEFLIRVFLRRDRIAQVGLFDARGQLTASVFVDDPEAFARQEPQFRRHDTVAAGEVEDFQRRASELLSQVPEGRAYAIS
APYLTGVRRRPAVVVAARAPGTRTGGLAAELGLEELSQRLAARGVGDERVFLLDGAGRLLLDGEPERERHEDFTGKLPGA
VGARQTGLAAYEEEGRAWLAAYSPVPELGWVAVVARPREAALAPLHALARSTYGVLGLTLLGVLALALMLARALARPIAR
LAEGARALARGNLAHRISLKRRDELGDLARAFNDMGQALEQAHRELLGFNEQLAAQVEERTRELQQTQVQLSRSQRLAAM
GDLAAGMAHEMNNPLAAVLGNVQLMLMDLPKEDPSHRMLGTVHQQAQRIASIVRELQLLSERQQLGRLPLDLHRMLQRVL
ESRCAELSQVGVHVDCRFHPGEVKVLGDTQALGDVLGRLLGNALNAMRDRPERNLVLSTQVVDAEVVRVEMKDTGRGIAR
EHLERIFNPFFTTKQQWTGKGLSLAVCHRVIEDHGGTITLDSVEGVGTTVTLVLPAAPASSGLV
```

Comment: no. this is just a demo. all the headers are different and unique. but they start with >. the only the specifications such as locus tag and everything beyond is different.

Comment: Maybe a good idea to explain the difference between the solution of the OP and yours.

Comment: @ShradhaSharma - Sorry... would you explain a bit more about exactly what you are interested in?  `[^>]` isolates what you are calling your header... If individual keyword/value pairs are the headers, then isolating them individually is also presented.

Comment: @ShradhaSharma - awesome man... glad you now have a success!  Will you do the team a favor and clarify a bit more to say you want to close on as "spaces within tags?"  Also please tag my answer as accepted... would help us a lot.  I had a problem with the tags actually... I wanted to use the regex of the form `[^\]] [^\[]` to identify tags... but that doesn't work in my version of sed... you may get a better answer than `[[:alnum:]] [[:alnum:]]` if you help us a little with your specific case.

Comment: I wanted all the spaces to be covered. In and out of tags. This makes further processing easier. Spaces create problems in filtering the data at later stages.